# Creating new column in csv using powershell with dynamic values

Tags: powershell, compare, import-csv, select-object

Hi I am trying to compare two csv and see the delta between them.
I want to create a new column in the csv to capture deactivated and new users comparing the old and new data extract.

Though I am able to create new column unable to populate values into the new column.
Here User_status is the column I am creating and it should hold deactivated value.

Here is a small portion of my code to see the deactivated users:

```
if ($csv2.UserID -match $user.UserID)
{
    Write-Verbose "$user.UserID is in both files"
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose "$user.UserID is missing from csv2"
    $missing += $user
    $user_status = 'Deactivated'
    #Set-Variable -Name "user_status" -Value "Deactivated"
    $missing | Select-Object *,@{Name='User_Status';Expression= { $_.user_status  } } |Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set the variable `$user_status` but then add `$_` when trying to call it. Instead just use the variable you populated

```
if ($csv2.UserID -match $user.UserID)
{
    Write-Verbose "$user.UserID is in both files"
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose "$user.UserID is missing from csv2"
    $missing += $user
    $user_status = 'Deactivated'
    #Set-Variable -Name "user_status" -Value "Deactivated"
    $missing | Select-Object *,@{Name='User_Status';Expression= { $user_status  } } |Export-Csv -path "C:\Users\test.csv" -NoTypeInformation 

}
```

As pointed out by @zett42, base variables expand fine inside of quotations, whereas accessing properties of a variable requires a subexpression

**Works fine**

```
"string with a simple $variable"
```

**Requires subexpression**

```
"string with complex $($variable.property)"
```